# Problems trying to create blurred background for modal view

Tags: uiblureffect

I am trying to show a view modally. The view is shown as a "Cross Dissolve" "over full screen". I am passing the screen shot to the controller. I am then trying to crop the screenshot and retain only the part that would be under the view. This i am blurring and adding to the view.

The code works as far as blurring goes, but i have two problems.
1) The image is at double scale, which will be something to do with retina display, but i am never sure how to fix that.
2) the other is that, having tried everything I can think of, i cannot get the coordinate of the "canvas" in a coordinate system that helps me correctly crop the view.

I'd really appreciate help with this
thanks
karl

```
    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let window = appDelegate.window!
    let splitViewController = window.rootViewController as! UISplitViewController;

    let cropFrame = UIView().convertRect(self.canvas.frame, toView: splitViewController.view)

    let croppedScreenShotCG = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(screenShot?.CGImage, cropFrame)
    let croppedScreenShot = UIImage(CGImage:croppedScreenShotCG)

    var blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.Light)
    var blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)

    blurEffectView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.canvas.frame.width, self.canvas.frame.height)

    let blurImageView = UIImageView(image:croppedScreenShot)
    blurImageView.addSubview(blurEffectView)

    let blurColorCast = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.canvas.frame.width, self.canvas.frame.height))
    blurColorCast.backgroundColor = UIColor.cloverColor10pc()
    blurColorCast.alpha = 0.2
    blurImageView.addSubview(blurColorCast)

    self.canvas.addSubview(blurImageView)
    self.canvas.sendSubviewToBack(blurImageView)

    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(croppedScreenShot, nil, nil, nil)
}
```

I am getting the screen shot like this:

```
            let layer = window.layer
        let scale = UIScreen.mainScreen().scale
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(layer.frame.size, false, scale);

        layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext())
        let screenshot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using UIImage's `CGImage:` you can use `imageWithCGImage:scale:orientation:` which takes a scale parameter to account for retina screens.

See: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIImage/imageWithCGImage:scale:orientation:

But personally I prefer to avoid doing anything in code, if there's a reasonable way to do it with storyboards.

Here's an [example project](https://github.com/mathewsanders/BlurExample) that has a blur effect for the back of a modal presentation that doesn't use *any* code at all.

The only thing worth noting is that for the view controller that's being presented, the root view background color is set to clear (otherwise the view controller that's presenting it would be obscured).

Comment: Thank you so much, I too would prefer to do this without code. Thanks for taking the time to reply.

Comment: Ok, this worked to start with. But something has changed. Now whenever I try to show view that is set to 'clear' it shows clear while transitioning into place, but once in place goes black. This happens everywhere i set a view to clear. Any ideas? thanks, karl

Comment: Hmm... In your segue attributes panel, is the presentation type set to 'Over Full Screen' (or 'Over Current Context')?

Comment: The segue is "Full Screen" and "Cover Vertical"

Comment: Change "Full Screen" to "Over Full Screen" and it should be good! Depending on the effect you're going for you might also want to change "Cover Vertical" to "Cross Dissolve".

Comment: The segue itself doesn't give that option, the navigation controller and view controller being displayed (modally) do. They are both set to "Over Full Screen" but still no clear view

Comment: Do i need to do anything with "Defines Context" and "Provides Context"?

Comment: When you click on the segue in the storyboard and view the attributes inspector in the utilities pane there should be options to enter the segue identifier, segue class etc. The 'Segue' option should be 'Present Modally' (UIPresentationController is intended for modal presentations) and 'Presentation' should be 'Over Full Screen'. Double check that, but if that's not it I'm not sure I can help without a sample project.

Comment: Ok, I finally got there, the options you mention were not available on the segue. However, they are on the navigation and view controllers. so i set the segue to "default" and "default" and the the navigation and view controllers as you suggest. It now seems to work. Thank you for all your, help.

Comment: Interestingly, doing this stops the unwind segue working! It fires, but doesn't dismiss the view. -- Just changed to another rewind point and seemed to work, strange

Comment: If you have a sample project if be happy to take a look later today. I thought that those options have been available for a while, but maybe they were added with Xcode 7 (assume that you're using Xcode 6.x)

Comment: Thanks, but I am happy to struggle with it for a bit now. The clear background is now working, and I have a workaround for the segue. Thanks for all your help, karl